# Flutter web background image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How to put image on background without image resizing when user changes size of window

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

Just use width and height properties.

for instance:

```
Image.asset('nameOfyourAsset', width: 32, height: 32)
```

or use

```
Image.asset('nameOfyourAsset', boxFit: none)
```